# Overriding custom cell initWithStyle method but it's not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell, I want to overwrite the init method like below:

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    self.buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.button1, self.button2,self.button3,self.button4, nil];
    self.labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.label1,self.label2,self.label3,self.label4, nil];
    NSLog(@"init done");
    return self;
}
```

I need this method to put my buttons and labels in the array. I am creating cells using the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FriendViewCell *cell = (FriendViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

However the init method is not being called and the arrays are nil. Not sure what is happening! Did I overwrite the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This initializer is called only when you call it explicitly. If you are loading your cells from a nib/storyboard, it won't be called.

Typically, we override `awakeFromNib` method to customize cells loaded from nibs.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4, nil];
    self.labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.label1, self.label2, self.label3, self.label4, nil];
}
```

Another note - instead of creating your `buttons` array from `button1`, `button2` etc. you can use an `IBOutletCollection`, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutletCollection NSArray *buttons;
```

and connect the buttons directly from Interface Builder but note that it doesn't keep the objects in any specific order.

Comment: I need to keep the buttons ordered, is there no way to call a custom init method from a storyboard then?

Comment: @Kex Not an `init` method. Use `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score -2):

You may try to use `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`.

Also make sure you didn't forget to set the custom class for the cell in Interface Builder (I assume you "defined" the custom cell in IB).

Comment: That won't work. In `initWithCoder:` the outlets are not yet connected.